# SBCL REPL use up arrow keys to show history

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, sbcl

I have installed `SBCL` onto OSX through Macports.
When inside the REPL, it would be very convenient to be able to use <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to iterate through the previous commands (similar to the behavior in bash or Python's REPL).

Is there a way to enable this functionality?

Comment: @LePetitPrince Seeing that you are the only person to provide anything close to an answer, you should change that comment to something I can mark as "accepted".

Comment: @LePetitPrince A "comment" is not an "answer" :-P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Install `rlwrap` and then run `rlwrap sbcl`.

You can get rlwrap through macports or homebrew.

It's pretty much as simple as that.

Comment: This answer is works if `rlwrap` and `sbcl` are installed via `brew`.

Comment: thanks, now i can really have fun with it.

Answer (score 4):

You could also also use [Linedit](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/linedit/). This is SBCL REPL specific, so it causes problems in other environments (like SLIME).

Or, you can try the [SBCL-Readline](https://github.com/jini-zh/sbcl-readline) project. Not sure how this works in SLIME, haven't tried it personally.

Both Uses UFFI to implement the use of C libraries. 
**Just make sure to skim through the source code and change the paths to libraries etc for your system**, before trying them out!